# Pyspark Dataframe not returning all rows while converting to pandas using toPandas or Pyarrow function in Pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyarrow

On trying to convert pyspark dataframe into pandas dataframe using arrow function only half the rows are getting converted. Pyspark df contains 170,000 rows.

```
>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
>> result_pdf = train_set.select("*").toPandas()
>> result_pdf returns only 65000 rows.
```

I tried to install and update pyarrow using following commands:

```
>> conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
>> pip install pyarrow
>> pip install pyspark[sql]
```

and then run

```
>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
>> result_pdf = train_set.select("*").toPandas()
>>spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
>> result_pdf = train_set.select("*").toPandas()
```

I am getting following warning message each time while conversion:

> C:\Users\MUM1342.conda\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\pyarrow__init__.py:152:
>   UserWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use
>   pyarrow.ipc.open_stream   warnings.warn("pyarrow.open_stream is
>   deprecated, please use "
>   C:\Users\MUM1342.conda\envs\snakes\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:2138:
>   UserWarning: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because
>   'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true, but has reached
>   the error below and can not continue. Note that
>   'spark.sql.execution.arrow.fallback.enabled' does not have an effect
>   on failures in the middle of computation.

Actual Output:

```
> train_set.count
> 170256
> result_pdf.shape
> 6500
```

Expected Output:

```
> train_set.count
> 170256
> result_pdf.shape
> 170256
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below if it works

Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
```

Comment: This didn't work.